# How to change variable value in an If statement in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, nagios

I'm not very familiar with bash scripting. This seems like its an easy problem to solve but my lack of experience with bash has me baffled.

I have a file which contains a list of Ip addresses and the corresponding Virtual machine name. What I want my program to do is get the ip and check for it in my file. Then when a match is found assign the Virtual Machine name to the variable VM so I can use it later.

```
IP = 10.XXX.XX.10
cat /be_vcenter_names.txt | 'VM = awk -F " "  {if ( $1==$IP) VM=$2}'
echo $VM # nothing shows here
```

Thanks for your help. I'll be happy to give more info as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture output of a command, use `$(...)`. Note that pipeline parts run in subshells, so you can't change a variable's value, as the change wouldn't be propagated back to the main shell.

```
VM=$(awk '$1 == "1.2.3.4" { print $2 }' < /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/be_vcenter_names.txt)
```

Comment: Could just be `VM=$(awk '$1=="1.2.3.4"{print $2}' file)`.

Comment: @choroba Thank you this worked. Instead of Hardcoding the ip when I use the Variable IP it wont work any ideas? 
*VM=$(awk '$1 == I$P { print $2 }' < /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/be_vcenter_names.txt)*

Comment: @EthanMcTiernan: Just use an awk variable: `awk -v ip=$IP '$1 == ip { print $2 }'`

Answer (score 0):

```
VM=$(awk -v ip=$IP '$1 == ip{print $2}' <file>)
```

[Awk accepts variables with -v switch.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)